# Email template variables not rendering from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, emails, registration

I am loading an email template for custom registration via a plugin.
I reset the template path and load my template like this:

```
    $oldPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();
    $newPath = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'businesslogic/templates';
    craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($newPath);
    $bodyhtml = craft()->templates->render('emailreg.html', array(
        'user' => $user
    ));
```

In my html template ( an evil abomination of tables etc ) I am accessing the user variable {{user.firstname}} just fine. But the other variable $user->mycustomfield will not render - even though I can send it in the subject line, e.g.,

```
$email->subject = 'New User Registration: ' . $user->firstName . ' ' . $user->registrationNumber;
```

So whats up here?

Comment: Weird/flaky this is a real blocker now. I can get other profile fields with user.myfield but not the one i want.....

Comment: Solved: had changed the user object variable so that one field was empty. Fine now. Phew

Comment: Can you please post an official answer, or close the question?

Answer (score 1):

The above template path code works fine. I was just looking for a user variable that hadn't yet been set